# Wordpress wp_update_post doesn't not trigger blog2social auto-repost plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, function, command-line-interface

I would like to update a WordPress post date from a PHP CLI script.

When I do this "by hand," - I edit the post on the WordPress back office editor - the blog2social plugin "auto-posts" the post on my social networks such as Facebook and Instagram. That's the expected behavior; I've configured blog2social in this way.

Now, I try to automate this, I use the "wp_update_post" function to update the post date to the current date, and the blog2social plugin "auto post" is not triggered.

**PHP Code**

```
require_once("/var/www/html/myblog/wp-load.php");

$id = 23056;
$date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

wp_update_post(
    array(
        'ID' => $id,
        'post_date' => $date_time,
        'post_date_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date($date_time),
        'post_modified' => $date_time,
        'post_modified_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date($date_time)
    ));
```

- Can you help me understand/debug why the blog2social plugin "auto post" is not triggered and does not plan to post on social networks?
- Can you share with my steps to steps to debug WordPress when I click on the post "update" button?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is the CLI script you are using to trigger the update post?

Comment: I edited the post to share the whole script